# How to run selenium tests on chrome if only binary file of chrome is placed in a server location in E drive

Tags: java, google-chrome, jenkins, webdriver, bitbucket

I have a situation in my project as below :

My code was executing as expected till the IT admin uninstalled chrome and FF from Jenkins server.

After raising a concern they placed a chrome binary in E drive .( E:\GC Local\GoogleChrome).But Chrome is not installed anywhere

I am facing issues to resolve this.

Do anyone guide here ?

Code I used :

```
if ("chrome".equals(browser))
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
System.getProperty("user.dir")
+ "\\src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will it work for you ?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("E:\\GC Local\\GoogleChrome");
```

Comment: When I used this code, I am getting the following error message: RRunning TestSuite
Browser :chrome
Error in initializing the Test .Details :- 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: 'ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setBinary("E://GCLocal//GoogleChrome//GoogleChromePortable.exe");
  
  
   options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
   options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
   driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
   clearCoockies(driver);}'

Answer (score 0):

I understand that in homepath \app data chrome should be installed by default to run chrome tests. In my case , there is no chrome istalled in homepath-app but in E drive

Answer (score 0):

When I used the below code :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.setBinary("E:\\GCLocal\\GoogleChrome\\GoogleChromePortable.exe");
      //  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\Browsers\\chromedriver.exe");              
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                        System.getProperty("user.dir")
                                + "\\src\\test\\resources\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");


       driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I am getting getting the following :

### T E S T S

Running TestSuite
Browser :chrome
Starting ChromeDriver 2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233) on port 45594
Only local connections are allowed.
Error in initializing the Test .Details :- 
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 62.74 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b1534ae328c771e0856c93e187490ca824', time: '2016-03-15 10:43:46'
System info: host: 'WHIS2002', ip: '10.192.129.112', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
./TestReport.html

Answer (score 0):

The above approach is correct. My issue was that portable-chrome binary refused to open due to some issues in server .code was fine.
This happened because of portable chrome binary performance issues which I solved like this :
Google Chrome Portable may run slowly from some flash drives. You can speed this up by copying GoogleChromePortable.ini from the GoogleChromePortable\Other\Source directory to the GoogleChromePortable directory and editing it to set RunLocally=true. If you do so, be sure to allow Google Chrome Portable time to copy your profile back after shutting it down. Of course, there are privacy implications to copying your personal data locally to a PC not under your control.

Thanks